# compiler warnings re: references to local variables

Tags: c++, reference, scope

So, I have these two functions `ref()` and `pointy()` that respectively create a local reference and pointer to a locally-defined int:

```
#include <iostream>

int& ref() {
  int knuckles = 6;
  int &chuckles = knuckles;
  return chuckles;
};

int* pointy() {
    int buckles = 8;
    return &buckles;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = ref(), *b = pointy();
    int c = 14, d = 20;
    std::cout << a << ' ' << *b << ' ' << c+d;
};
```

The code compiles fine, and it gives a warning about returning the address of local variable `buckles`, but what concerns me is that it doesn't say anything about `ref()` returning a reference to `knuckles`.
Is my compiler (g++ via MinGW, if it makes a difference) just sleeping on the job? Is there something about references that keeps the referent from going out of scope? Or is my reference syntax just bad?

Much obliged!

Comment: But you're not returning a reference to `knuckles`, you're returning `chuckles` which could quite easily have been assigned to a non-local reference.

Comment: You have it the wrong way around: your compiler is doing you a huge favor by pointing out the problem in `pointy`. It is not required to do that. You've successfully tricked it into not seeing the problem in `ref`.

Comment: The compiler is not required to diagnose any of these errors. Be thankful it catches even one of them. (It fails to recognize the error in `ref` because you smuggled it inside another variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two test cases aren't parallel. This program:

```
#include <iostream>

int& ref() {
  int knuckles = 6;
  return knuckles;
};

int* pointy() {
    int buckles = 8;
    return &buckles;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = ref(), *b = pointy();
    int c = 14, d = 20;
    std::cout << a << ' ' << *b << ' ' << c+d;
};
```

Produces these warnings:

```
$ g++ -O4 -std=c++0x    x.cc   -o x
x.cc: In function ‘int& ref()’:
x.cc:4:7: warning: reference to local variable ‘knuckles’ returned [enabled by default]
x.cc: In function ‘int* pointy()’:
x.cc:9:9: warning: address of local variable ‘buckles’ returned [enabled by default]
```